# DNS Management in Azure

Tags: dns, azure-web-app-service

I have been having this problem for a while now whereby all my web apps on azure have the same ip address so it even becomes an issue performing DNS management.

I tried to look up the ip address for my web app using whatsmydns.net and it cannot resolve well.

I am thinking that the problem is becomes all my web apps have the same ip address. Does anyone know how to work around this problem?

Your help will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to read [this article](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/documentation/articles/web-sites-custom-domain-name/) for more information about map a custom dns record to Azure web app. If you want to use an A record to map to your Azure app's IP address, you need to create **both an A record and a TXT record**. we can use whatsmydns.net to check the DNS propagation via input our custom dns record.